# (Android) Get upload progress from Socket Outputstream.write()?

Tags: java, android, sockets, progressdialog, file-transfer

I am making an Android application to transfer files from the device to a Java application on a computer. It works in the sense that it can send files to the computer, but while it sends it has a `ProgressDialog`. The dialog is **not** meant to monitor the progress of **reading from the SD card**, but instead the progress of **uploading to the server**. So far my searches have only come up with reading from a SD card or a webpage.

To upload, I am using a simple `OutputStream` that is created with `socket.getOutputStream();`. My code is as follows:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {
    String IP = params[1];
    File myFile = new File(params[0]);
    int count;
    try {
        long total = 0;
        Socket socket = new Socket(IP, 25000);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream(); // THIS IS MY OUTPUTSTREAM
        while((count = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            progress = (int) (count);
            publishProgress();
            out.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            Log.i("TOTAL", Long.toString(total));
            Log.i("Upload progress", "" + (int) ((total * 100) / buffer.length));
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("TAG", "Failed to send file");
    }
    return "test";
}
```

From my research on the documentation and other forums, it seems like OutputStream has no methods that return anything. This is troublesome as I need to return its current status on the upload.

As of right now, the progress dialog goes from 0 to max instantly regardless of the file size (it just takes much longer to actually do so). I don't know what could be causing this, but that's not the point.

**How can I monitor the upload progress of a file using OutputStream?** Is this possible to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you have created buffer with your file size:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
```

So you cycle passes only 1 time because is enough space for data

```
while((count = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)
```

You need to change on something like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
```